# PostgreSQL - When do indices get build and when to use CONCURRENTLY?

Tags: postgresql

I'm fairly inexperienced with SQL (or here PostgreSQL) and I'm trying to understand and use indices correctly.

PostgreSQL has a `CONCURRENTLY` option for `CREATE INDEX` and [the documentation says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY):

> "*When this option is used, PostgreSQL must perform two scans of the table, and in addition it must wait for all existing transactions that could potentially use the index to terminate. Thus this method requires more total work than a standard index build and takes significantly longer to complete. However, since it allows normal operations to continue while the index is built, this method is useful for adding new indexes in a production environment.*"

- Does this mean that an `INDEX` is only created at startup or during a migration process?

I know that one can re-index tables if they get fragmented over time (not sure how this actually happens and why an index is just not kept "up-to-date") and that re-indexing helps the database to get more efficient again.

- Can I benefit from `CONCURRENTLY` during such a re-index process?

and besides that I'm asking myself

- Are there situation where I should avoid `CONCURRENTLY` or would it hurt to use `CONCURRENTLY` just on every `INDEX` I create?

Comment: What do you mean by `at startup` and `during a migration process` ?

Comment: @wildplasser By "*at startup*" I mean the startup of the PostgreSQL server that might be necessary after a restart of the whole server instance. By "*during a migration process*" I mean if I e.g. create a new index on an existing table that already contains data.

Comment: "startup" : an index **is** a table (technically). It is kept on disk, just like ordinary tables. "migration" : that could be called a DDL-operation (data definition language) It is basically a change to an existing schema (model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was sensible to always `create index ... concurrently` it'd be the default.

What it does is builds the index with weaker locks held on the table being indexed, so you can continue to insert, update, delete, etc.

This comes at a price:

- You can't use `create index ... concurrently` in a transaction, unlike almost all other DDL
- The index build can take longer
- The index built may be less efficiently laid out (slower, bigger)
- Rarely, the `create index` can fail, so you have to drop and recreate the index

You can't easily use this to re-create an existing index. PostgreSQL doesn't yet support `reindex ... concurently`. There are workarounds where you create a new index, then swap old and new indexes, but it's very difficult if you're trying to do it for a unique index or primary key that's the target of a foreign key constraint.

Unless you know you need it, just use `create index` without `concurrently`.

Comment: "*If it was sensible to always* `create index ... concurrently` *it'd be the default.*" makes perfect sense! Thank you! :)